# windows phone 8 how to swipe local html files just like pivot or panaroma control?

Tags: windows-phone-8

i'm beginner for windows phone 8., actually i have created a project which has some html files(40 files) in local folder and i want to show all html files one by one when user swipe horizontally just like pivot or panaroma control., 
i know statically how to call local html files by using web browser control and i did in many projects., but i don't know to show all files one by one when user swipe horizontally.,

and i tried to dynamically add web browser control inside pivot item.,

this is my code for create dynamic pivot items with web browser controls inside

" pivotPage.cs "

```
  void pivotPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
         {
              for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
              {
               string _url = "ways/a"+ i + ".html";
               PivotItem newPivotItem = new PivotItem();
               newPivotItem.Margin = new Thickness(0, -10, 0, 0);
               WebBrowser newWebBrowser = new WebBrowser();
               newWebBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(_url, UriKind.Relative));
               newPivotItem.Content = newWebBrowser;
               pivotList.Items.Add(newPivotItem);
              }
         }
```

and my pivotPage.xaml is

```
  <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Background="#FF378FB1">
        <phone:Pivot x:Name="pivotList" Background="White" Margin="10,130,10,80"/>
    </Grid>
```

if i try to create maximum of " 25 " pivot items using for loop like this means i got output with 25 pivot items and i can able to swipe., the code like this

```
  for(int i=0; i<25; i++)
  {
    string _url = "ways/a"+ i + ".html";
    PivotItem newPivotItem = new PivotItem();
    newPivotItem.Margin = new Thickness(0, -10, 0, 0);
    WebBrowser newWebBrowser = new WebBrowser();
    newWebBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(_url, UriKind.Relative));
    newPivotItem.Content = newWebBrowser;
    pivotList.Items.Add(newPivotItem);
  }
```

but i need to show 40 files, so if i make condition like this means

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
  {

  }
```

it shows nothing and app was closed.,

is there any limit for maximum no.of pivot items shown ???

```
  could you please some one try to give me solution for this and also 

  tell me that is there any control for showing html files like swipe view?
```

simply said my requirement is " how to show local html files one by one like swipe view in WP8 apps ?"

thanks in advance., am waiting for some answers.,

Answer (score 0):

Finally i find answer myself like this and it works for me.,

Step 1: for displaying collection of contents (html , image , text etc) use data binding concept to create UI in xaml page like this.,

```
    <phone:Pivot x:Name="pivotList" Margin="0,0,0,80" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
           <!-- <phone:Pivot.Title>
                <TextBlock Text="40 ways to lose belly fat" FontSize="28" Foreground="#FF00FFEE"></TextBlock>
            </phone:Pivot.Title>-->
            <phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding _title}" Foreground="#FF00FFEE" FontSize="48"></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                <phone:WebBrowser Name="browser" Source="{Binding _url}" Margin="20,-10,20,0">
                </phone:WebBrowser>
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        </phone:Pivot>
```

and then in code behind .cs file

```
   public partial class pivotPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private List<TList> _pivotList;
    public pivotPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += pivotPage_Loaded;

    }

    void pivotPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _pivotList = new List<TList>();
        int j = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
        {
            _pivotList.Add(new TList 
            {
                _title="flat Belly Tip-"+j,
                _url="ways/a"+ i + ".html"
            });
            j++;
        }
        pivotList.DataContext = _pivotList;
    }
```

i got that idea from this post

```
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004493/databinding-dynamic-pivot
```

Hope this ll help.,

Comment: If there is a lot of html files and if there are any manipulations u have to do with html files , like On LoadComplete event do some javascript execution or on Drag event of browser content do some actions etc . In this case is this approach is an efficient one?